# How do I limit platforms that I build for?

Tags: android-ndk, build.gradle, gradle-experimental

I've tried doing `abiFilters ["armeabi-v7a"]` instead of `abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")` but that results in linking error and message:

```
Execution failed for task ':linkMyModuleArm64-v8aDebugSharedLibrary'
```

Basing on this message I suspect that project is still build for all platforms...

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `model` block create `android.productFlavors` block (you should already have this). Then apply your abiFilter like this:

```
create("arm"){
    dimension = "abi"
    ndk.abiFilters.addAll(['armeabi'])
}
```

Adding `abiFilters.addAll(['armeabi'])` to your main `ndk` block, would set the default for all "Variants"

Have a look at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-Other-Build-Options